# Trying to use Nodejs Library morgan-body

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

How can I save morganBody(app); response to a file instead of console. I am learning node.js.
[image]
Basically i want to save this request response in a log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from morgan-body [github](https://github.com/sirrodgepodge/morgan-body#morganbodyexpress-instance-options-object), for more options you should check that.

Basically `morganBody` takes 2 arguments, **express instance** and **options** object, inside options you can provide stream for writing to file, or any object which has `write` function and it will call that function  instead of writing to `stdout`.

Example:

```
morganBody(app, {stream: fs.createWriteStream('./logFileName.log', {flags: 'a'})});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Final structure is morganBody(app, {"stream":logger.stream});

Comment: and in stream to remove ansi color codes i write a regex module.exports.stream = {
    write: function(message, encoding){
     var logs= message.replace(
  /[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g, '');
        logger.info(logs);
       // logger.debug(message);
    }